# Set font colour 'fetch row' to red

Tags: php, arrays, colors

How can I set the following to the colour red?

```
$sub_array[] = $row["Certified"].' '.$row["date_certified"];
```

Comment: I think you need to be more specific.

Comment: Ok. This is field from a database that would be displayed on a webpage the font colour by default is black but I want to change this particular field to display as font color red

Comment: Can I see where you actually display it onto the webpage, like with `echo` or whatever function you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$sub_array[] = '<span style="color:red;">'.$row["Certified"].' '.$row["date_certified"].'</span>';
```

and if the text still is black, then try:

```
$sub_array[] = '<span style="color:red !important;">'.$row["Certified"].' '.$row["date_certified"].'</span>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked

Comment: great the hear! 